# When to use sixth in continuo according to Bianciardi?

Tags: theory, history, baroque-period, figured-bass

From Bianciardi's Breve Regola (http://www.bassus-generalis.org/bianciardi/bianciardi.html): "But because some notes don’t have a fifth above, a sixth
is used in its place; this happens in those keys in which,
in moving from one to the other, mutations of the fourth
occur; as when you sing B to F (with no flats) and when
you sing from E to B (with a b-flat)."

I don't understand the example, on which chord should the sixth be used instead?

Answer (score 1):

The example is transcribed incorrectly.  There should be a flat in the key signature of the example in bass clef.  The first image of the source that I found was https://fridaystuff.com/product/early-music-sources-francesco-bianciardi-breve-regola/

Thus, with a key signature of one flat, with an E in the bass, one uses the sixth instead of the fifth.

They also got the last chord of the tenor clef part wrong; it should be B-D-G, not E-G-C.  This makes sense because the tenor clef example is the one for the B-natural signature.  With that signature, and B in the bass, use G instead of F.

The translator added a footnote that implies that the error in the tenor clef was in the source for that translation; if so, it was a different source from the one linked above.

No wonder you were confused!

Comment: oh okay! thank you. the wording in the translation was a bit confusing

Answer (score 0):

According to the later example, he means that the chord B-D-F should be replaced with B-D-G (I assume if no diminished chord is needed.) and E-G-Bb should be replaced with E-G-C.

Comment: The translator of the linked examples has added a footnote about an error in the bass clef examples, but the error is theirs: they have overlooked the fact that the bass clef example has a signature of one flat.